# SQL select two columns from one entry

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

How can I query two columns from one with regular expression in the ending of the entry?

Table IMAGES:

```
IMAGE_NAME         IMAGE_ID
---------------------------
image01_01.png     0
image01_02.png     1
image02_01.png     2
image02_02.png     3
```

```
select
    IMAGE_NAME,
    IMAGE_ID,
    <img src="https://my_page?im_id='||IMAGE_ID||'" class="test" height="50" width="200">' IMAGE
from 
    IMAGES
where 
    IMAGE_NAME like '%01.png'
```

Shows me all images with 01.png ending in the image name. In addition I need a second column which show me all images with 02.png ending in the image name.

How to achieve this query to get two columns?

Edit: I want to display two image columns in an interactive report in Apex.

Edit #2: it's getting more complex when displaying the images with img tag.

The expected column results should be an html image object which can be displayed in Apex:

https://my_page?im_id=0

```
Suffix_01       | Suffix_02       | Link to image_01       | Link to image_02
----------------+-----------------+------------------------+-----------------
image02_01.png  | image02_02.png  |https://my_page?im_id=2 | https://my_page?im_id=3
image01_01.png  | image01_02.png  |https://my_page?im_id=0 |https://my_page?im_id=1
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Incorrect `select` statement, because of comma before `from` instruction.

Comment: I am using oracle

Comment: Having the data in two columns is not a meaningful result-set because then each row's columns have nothing to do with each other. Why do you want two columns instead of two result-sets - or a `UNION` of results?

Comment: If you're wanting to **display** the data in two columns somewhere (a web-page?) then arranging results into UI display/grid columns is not something you should be doing in SQL.

Comment: Yes exactly, I edit my question.

Comment: "I want to display two image columns in an interactive report in Apex." - then you should run **two separate queries** (one for `01.png` and the other for `02.png`) and combine them in Apex.

Comment: @snowflake Can you complete your example adding "second column" to your question?

Comment: What's the expected result if you have 4 different 01.png files, but only 2 02.png files?

Comment: @jarlh Then no entry. There will be always two images.

Comment: Your data model is inappropriate. The DBMS doesn't see that two images belong together, because you are hiding this in the image name. Make this implicit with an additional column and such tasks become easier. The same is true for 01/02 in the image names. If one picture is your primary one and the other is secondary, then have a column to indicate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want a table having in one-row image names with the same prefix. You can use conditional aggregation for it:

```
SELECT 
    t.suffix01, 
    t.suffix02, 
    'https://my_page?im_id=' || i1.image_id "Link to image_01", 
    'https://my_page?im_id=' || i2.image_id "Link to image_02"
FROM
    (SELECT 
         MAX(CASE WHEN Image_name like '%01.png' THEN Image_name END) suffix01,
         MAX(CASE WHEN Image_name like '%02.png' THEN Image_name END) suffix02
     FROM 
         Images
     GROUP BY 
         SUBSTR(image_name, 1, LENGTH(image_name) - 6)) t 
JOIN 
    images i1 ON i1.image_name = t.suffix01
JOIN  
    images i2 ON i2.image_name = t.suffix02
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=018dcb23c604863c7799cc6baf61cef0)

**Result:**

```
suffix01        | suffix02        | Link to image_01        | Link to image_02
----------------+-----------------+-------------------------+------------------
image02_01.png  | image02_02.png  | https://my_page?im_id=2 | https://my_page?im_id=3
image01_01.png  | image01_02.png  | https://my_page?im_id=0 |https://my_page?im_id=1
```

Comment: I'd make this `GROUP BY SUBSTR(image_name, 1, LENGTH(image_name) - 6)` in order to deal with any number of underlines in the file names ('some_image_01.png', 'otherimage01png').

Comment: Thanks this worked but now I have some problems with displaying the images next to each other. How to query another column (image_id), which is needed for the image tag? I edit my question, sorry about that.

Comment: Post expected result as well

Comment: I added the results

Comment: @RadimBača This works but I get only the last two entries of my database.

Comment: Please update mydbfiddle demo that I could see the case when it is not working

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c545e16539d491e8cdd0cce6d015b666

Comment: Ok, then use the `GROUP BY ` proposed by @ThorstenKettner https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c9db116ae3a4f7ebc93a8f1ff9a7257

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot @RadimBačaand and ThorstenKettner, I appreciate your help and not very experienced with SQL.